# Python: Handling requests exceptions the right way

Tags: python, django, exception, error-handling, request

I recently switched from urlib2 to requests and I'm not sure how to deal with exceptions. What is best practice? My current code looks like this, but is not doing any good:

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
except requests.ConnectionError , e:
    logging.error('ConnectionError = ' + str(e.code))
    return False
except requests.HTTPError , e:
    logging.error('HTTPError = ' + str(e.reason))
    return False
except requests.Timeout, e:
    logging.error('Timeout')
    return False
except requests.TooManyRedirects:
    logging.error('TooManyRedirects')
    return False
except Exception:
    import traceback
    logging.error('generic exception: ' + traceback.format_exc())
    return False
```

Comment: Depends on what your goal is. Do you want to know about every specific exception, or do you just want to detect any failure?

Comment: No I don't want to know about every specific exception. What is common practice?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since it looks bad as a comment, have you tried:

```
try:
    # some code
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: That seems to work, but it's hard to test all for all errors. Thanks! I'll try to play a bit more with it.